# Where to keep global variables when running WCF server hosted in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have simple web site with WCF service hosted in it. Looks like during each `WCF` service web method call new class inherited from `ServiceContract` interface is created. Where I can add global variables accessible from WCF methods that will not bee disposed after web method finises its job? Assume I need to have web method calls counter.

Comment: You could use static fields.  Also look at the following article about instancing of WCF services: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use storage outside the WCF to avoid it being reset on recycles. Configuration/application files, databases etc.